# How can I group XML nodes of the same name?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I am trying to figure out how to group XML nodes with the same name but different values.

The web service I'm using returns an XmlElement that looks like this:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Name name="Name">Item 1</Name>
        <Description name="Description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </Description>
        <AssociatedItems name="Associated Items">Item 2</AssociatedItems>
        <AssociatedItems name="Associated Items">Item 3</AssociatedItems>
        <AssociatedItems name="Associated Items">Item 4</AssociatedItems>
        <AssociatedItems name="Associated Items">Item 5</AssociatedItems>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

I am transforming each node into an HTML tag

```
protected void lnkItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)link.Parent.Parent;

    string id = gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["id"].ToString();

    PublicApiAsmxServiceSoapClient service = new PublicApiAsmxServiceSoapClient("PublicApiAsmxServiceSoap", WEB_SERVICE_URL);
    XmlElement xml = service.ItemGetAsXml(id);
    XElement nodes = XElement.Parse(xml.InnerXml);

    foreach (var node in nodes.Elements())
    {
        InsertHTML(node);
    }
}

private void InsertHTML(XElement node)
{
    if (node.Value == string.Empty)
        return;

    pnl.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<h3>{0}</h3>", node.Attribute("name").Value)));
    pnl.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", node.Value)));
}
```

With my code right now, the HTML output would be:

```
<h3>Name</h3>
<p>Item 1</p>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h3>Associated Items</h3>
<p>Item 2</p>
<h3>Associated Items</h3>
<p>Item 3</p>
<h3>Associated Items</h3>
<p>Item 4</p>
<h3>Associated Items</h3>
<p>Item 5</p>
```

Is there a way to group the same nodes as an unordered list? Something like this, perhaps:

```
<h3>Name</h3>
<p>Item 1</p>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h3>Associated Items</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you! (Please be nice.)

PS
The child nodes that repeat aren't limited to AssociatedTerms only. There are possibly more child nodes of the same name that repeat.

Comment: Here is very good [link](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/linq/linq-to-xml-%28silverlight-quickstart%29). Using LINQ to XML you can accomplish what you want. Look for <b>Grouping an RSS XML Tree by Category</b> in this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easiest using a generator to generate the elements based on the groupings since what gets generated depends on how many duplicates there are.

As I understand it, you're grouping by element name and the value of the `name` attributes.  Then generating an `h3` followed by an element depending on if there are multiple elements in the group.  `p` if there's a single element or a `ul` if there are multiple elements.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> GroupedElements(XElement root)
{
    var groupedItems =
        from element in root.Elements()
        group element
        by new
        {
            Element = element.Name,
            Name = (string)element.Attribute("name"),
        };
    foreach (var g in groupedItems)
    {
        yield return new XElement("h3", g.Key.Name);
        var isMultiple = g.Skip(1).Any();
        if (isMultiple)
            yield return new XElement("ul",
                from item in g
                select new XElement("li", item.Value.Trim())
            );
        else
            yield return new XElement("p", g.Single().Value.Trim());
    }
}
```

```
var xmlStr = @"<Items>
    <Item>
        <Name name=""Name"">Item 1</Name>
        <Description name=""Description"">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </Description>
        <AssociatedItems name=""Associated Items"">Item 2</AssociatedItems>
        <AssociatedItems name=""Associated Items"">Item 3</AssociatedItems>
        <AssociatedItems name=""Associated Items"">Item 4</AssociatedItems>
        <AssociatedItems name=""Associated Items"">Item 5</AssociatedItems>
    </Item>
</Items>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var transformed = new XElement("div", 
    from item in doc.XPathSelectElements("/Items/Item")
    select GroupedElements(item)
);
```

Yields the following:

```xml
<div>
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <h3>Description</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <h3>Associated Items</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it the best solution but you can try something like this

```
       List<string> items = new List<string>();
          XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
            if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                InsertHTML(rdr.LocalName.ToString(), rdr.Value.ToString());
            }
          }
        private void InsertHTML(string name, string value)
        {
            if (value == string.Empty)
                return;
            if(name=="AssociatedItems")
             {

               items.add(value);
             }
             else
             {
            pnl.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<h3>{0}</h3>", name)));
            pnl.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", value)));
             }
        }
           pnl.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<h3>{0}</h3>", "Associated Items")));
           pnl.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<ul>")));
        foreach(var item in items)
        {

          pnl.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("<li>{0}</li>", item)));

        }
         pnl.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("</ul>")));
```

Comment: The thing is, it has more nodes than just that. So there can be other node names that are the same.

Comment: ohh you mean any element of the same name you want to view in list

Comment: @omgdork they are not really child element you might format your xml differently to make them child elements

Comment: yes! unfortunately, that's the format of the xml the service returns. Is there any way to format it after retrieving from the service?

Comment: @omgdork do you know all the name of the elements that might be repeated or you just check if the element is repeated more that ones you want to display it in list

Comment: no, I don't know all the names of the elements. I just need to check if a certain element name repeats :)

Comment: @omgdork you can add all names to list and than find what elements are repepeated in list

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use XSLT, you could use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="grouping" match="Item/*" use="@name"/>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:apply-templates
         select="*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('grouping', @name)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item/*">
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h3>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count(key('grouping', @name))=1">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></p>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('grouping', @name)">
            <ul><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></ul>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </li>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```